# Adding New Cocoa Touch Framework in existing swift project clashes with Objective-C cocoa pod files

Tags: ios, c, swift

I've added New Cocoa touch framework inside my existing swift project. Yet I haven't integrated any C files inside it and build it for the very first time, which results in numerous errors looks like clashes between newly added cocoa touch framework & `Objective-C` pod files.

[image]

How to solve these errors? Below are my linked frameworks.

[image]

Comment: Can you try to post the linked libraries in your target? (Project settings > Your target > Linked Frameworks and Libraries)

Comment: @BojanDimovski I've updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: What is the source of the `libSignal.framework`? Is it this wrapped library https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-c?

Comment: @BojanDimovski Yes, but for now I've just added two simple .c and .h files include 1 function.

Comment: @BojanDimovski once I'm able to achieve calling that function from my end. will integrate libsignal src file inside libSignal.framework.

Comment: I'd suggest following these step-by-step instructions https://distillery.com/blog/how-to-integrate-a-c-library-into-an-ios-app-written-in-swift/.